# Unknown noise in uwsim 3D range mapping

Tags: ros, sonar, ros-kinetic, uwsim, range

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with UWSim, and I have modelled a rotating multibeam on the AUV (like a lidar on a car) that maps the 3D surroundings of the robot, creating a "range map".

I am facing a type of noise in my range values that I cannot determine (see photo). A part from the seafloor (shown above because I got a mess in the TF tree most probably and I haven't managed to put it below the AUV tf), one can see how sparse voxels are mapped as well.

[image: image description]

They appear behind the AUV (where there is nothing), and mapped at many different ranges.

Is the sonar assigning a wrong range to the tail of the AUV because of it being too close maybe?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283431/unknown-noise-in-uwsim-3d-range-mapping/) by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem. The noise comes from false measurements of the sonar.
The tail of the AUV might be too close to the sensor to provide good ranges, and so they are mapped in the wrong position.
I do not know if UWSim provides a "cleaner" sonar.

---

Originally posted by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) with karma: 101 on 2018-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0